# faithful representation of a group and its subgroup

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Suppose we are considering the representation of a group $G$ and its normal subgroup $H$. Suppose the representation of $H$ is faithful, does it imply that the representation of $G$ is also faithful?

Intuitively, the representation of a subgroup should not imply the representation of a whole group, so intuition tells me it is no. But a concrete example seems to suggest it is yes.

The example is $G=U(1)$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}_N$. A faithful representation of $H=\mathbb{Z}_N$ is a phase $e^{i2\pi k/N }$ where $k=0, 1, ..., N-1$. Then it seems that one can not construct a non-faithful representation of the whole group $U(1)$. So is there anything going wrong with the example, or anything wrong with the intuition?

Edit: Let us not consider the example where $G=H \times ...$, because in that case the intuition is obviously correct. Thanks Jyrki Lahtonen for suggesting this.

Comment: What about $U(1) \to \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ sending $\phi$ to rotation by $3\phi$? This is faithful on the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Let $G=U(1)\times U(1)$. Then you will find counterexamples easily.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks! Indeed. The example in my mind is like $U(1)-Z_N$. I wonder in that case, is the intuition still correct?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Let me understand: Are you suggesting that $U(1)$ is not faithful, but $\mathbb{Z}_2$ now is faithful?

Comment: I think so, yes, because e.g. $\phi = 2\pi / 3$ gets sent to the identity. On the other hand, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ only consists of $\phi = 0$ and $\phi = \pi$, which get sent to $0$ and $3\pi$ (i.e. $\pi$) respectively.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Thanks!